# Как мне в цикл while скормить каждый раз новую переменную?

Tags: php, циклы

**Как мне в цикл while скормить каждый раз новую переменную?**

**Допустим, есть три переменные:**

```
    $tier5 = '1%2C6417%2C61457%2C1057%2C35329%2C5649%2C53585%2C1377%2C3457%2C1041%2C54017%2C11777%2C9761%2C8785%2C13985%2C1137%2C18689%2C5409%2C16145%2C16385%2C13393%2C4657%2C31265%2C32769%2C54545%2C10529%2C4417%2C51553%2C7217%2C53761%2C51745%2C34385%2C15009%2C55057%2C6945%2C18193%2C2113%2C4161%2C59409%2C52257%2C2129%2C9121%2C2977%2C32273%2C9473%2C3361%2C35153%2C11169%2C34897%2C1473%2C31249%2C2577%2C60689%2C16033%2C257%2C2897%2C10049%2C5729%2C5393%2C47105%2C35345%2C34305%2C33297%2C1153%2C2193%2C51457%2C51473%2C61809%2C64801%2C54353%2C14145%2C6721%2C51713%2C33%2C12881%2C12577%2C4129%2C11089';

    $tier6 = '11265%2C57361%2C3585%2C5025%2C273%2C1313%2C11585%2C57105%2C37649%2C13217%2C4673%2C33361%2C52321%2C3713%2C2817%2C59681%2C1889%2C10017%2C7185%2C53841%2C12289%2C15889%2C1105%2C64817%2C801%2C5633%2C16641%2C7473%2C9553%2C11793%2C5169%2C16673%2C1553%2C9809%2C15521%2C14097%2C15137%2C31585%2C2625%2C1729%2C7201%2C14417%2C64545%2C51345%2C11425%2C58625%2C11553%2C31057%2C2449%2C33105%2C3665%2C9729%2C57681%2C55889%2C51569%2C54785%2C1409%2C4913%2C56145%2C5473%2C6465%2C59393%2C16417%2C31825%2C145%2C10497%2C41249%2C32337%2C1393%2C51585%2C61553%2C10001%2C4689%2C2561%2C11857%2C52753%2C12961%2C35857%2C58113%2C35585%2C41761%2C57169%2C2321';

    $tier7 = '19457%2C33825%2C37121%2C33041%2C36881%2C529%2C16129%2C1569%2C11681%2C5217%2C2337%2C5457%2C3633%2C513%2C49921%2C7233%2C12705%2C1121%2C35089%2C3153%2C18961%2C1793%2C3873%2C32865%2C4113%2C2305%2C1649%2C3857%2C6977%2C1665%2C36097%2C2705%2C36609%2C5281%2C33553%2C14753%2C7729%2C37633%2C10065%2C56353%2C15649%2C55569%2C56609%2C26177%2C11025%2C5889%2C7969%2C16289%2C55297%2C3377%2C11345%2C6657%2C10817%2C8961%2C9249%2C57617%2C1297%2C8977%2C19745%2C32049%2C305%2C59937%2C11041%2C14161%2C26945%2C54097%2C10769%2C59137%2C10241%2C59649%2C63809%2C3969%2C32849%2C5185%2C61713%2C15265%2C12545%2C39457%2C62993%2C1985%2C14353%2C14497%2C46593%2C35409%2C31761%2C1073%2C55121%2C32017%2C36177';
```

**Пишу цикл:**

```
$i = 5;

while ($i<=7)
{
$tierX = '$tier'.$i;

$getXtier = ('https://urlsait='.$tierX);

echo $getXtier."<br>";
$i++;
}
```

**На выводе переменные выводит имена, а не значения. Как вывести именно значения каждой переменной в цикле?**

```
https://urlsait=$tier5
https://urlsait=$tier6
https://urlsait=$tier7
```

**Должно быть так:**

```
https://urlsait=1%2C6417%2C61457%2C1057%2C35329%2C5649%2C53585%2C1377%2C3457%2C1041%2C54017%2C11777%2C9761%2C8785%2C13985%2C1137%2C18689%2C5409%2C16145%2C16385%2C13393%2C4657%2C31265%2C32769%2C54545%2C10529%2C4417%2C51553%2C7217%2C53761%2C51745%2C34385%2C15009%2C55057%2C6945%2C18193%2C2113%2C4161%2C59409%2C52257%2C2129%2C9121%2C2977%2C32273%2C9473%2C3361%2C35153%2C11169%2C34897%2C1473%2C31249%2C2577%2C60689%2C16033%2C257%2C2897%2C10049%2C5729%2C5393%2C47105%2C35345%2C34305%2C33297%2C1153%2C2193%2C51457%2C51473%2C61809%2C64801%2C54353%2C14145%2C6721%2C51713%2C33%2C12881%2C12577%2C4129%2C11089
```

Comment: Для этого созданы массивы.

Comment: "$tier" . $i; 
https://bloxcms.net/documentation/templates-php-quotes.htm

Comment: @Kirill не поможет. `"$tier" . $i;` - получится ссылка на несуществующую переменную `$tier`. Попробуйте `$tier5 = 'abc'; $i = 5; var_dump("$tier".$i);`

Comment: @tutankhamun точно. тогда  ${'tier' . $i};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал @u_mulder лучше использовать массивы.

```
$tiers = ['1%2',
'11265',
'19457'
];

foreach($tiers as $tier){
    echo 'https://urlsait=' . $tier . "\n";
}
```

я не писал полностью ваши значения так как они очень длинные, подставите в массив `$tiers` который я написал выше.

Comment: И донесите до него (Рената) о кавычках. ответ хороший, но в вопросе-то проблема в другом

Answer (score 1):

Немного научу плохому. (*Да, конечно, эта задача решается с использованием массивов. Не очень понятно зачем эти переменные вообще определяются порознь, а не сразу в массиве, но это другой вопрос*).

В коде, указанном в вопросе, достаточно добавить всего один символ `$`. Вместо

```
$getXtier = ('https://urlsait='.$tierX);
```

нужно написать

```
$getXtier = ('https://urlsait='.$$tierX);
```

Это называется "[Переменные переменных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php)" - нечасто используемая особенность PHP.

**Обновлено** Как верно подмечено в комментариях, также ошибка в том что `'$tier'.$i` должно быть `'tier'.$i`

В итоге получаем вот такой (не очень удачный, но работающий) код

```
$tier5 = '1%2C6417%2C61457%2C1057%2C35329%2C5649%2C53585%2C1377%2C3457%2C1041%2C54017%2C11777%2C9761%2C8785%2C13985%2C1137%2C18689%2C5409%2C16145%2C16385%2C13393%2C4657%2C31265%2C32769%2C54545%2C10529%2C4417%2C51553%2C7217%2C53761%2C51745%2C34385%2C15009%2C55057%2C6945%2C18193%2C2113%2C4161%2C59409%2C52257%2C2129%2C9121%2C2977%2C32273%2C9473%2C3361%2C35153%2C11169%2C34897%2C1473%2C31249%2C2577%2C60689%2C16033%2C257%2C2897%2C10049%2C5729%2C5393%2C47105%2C35345%2C34305%2C33297%2C1153%2C2193%2C51457%2C51473%2C61809%2C64801%2C54353%2C14145%2C6721%2C51713%2C33%2C12881%2C12577%2C4129%2C11089';
$tier6 = '11265%2C57361%2C3585%2C5025%2C273%2C1313%2C11585%2C57105%2C37649%2C13217%2C4673%2C33361%2C52321%2C3713%2C2817%2C59681%2C1889%2C10017%2C7185%2C53841%2C12289%2C15889%2C1105%2C64817%2C801%2C5633%2C16641%2C7473%2C9553%2C11793%2C5169%2C16673%2C1553%2C9809%2C15521%2C14097%2C15137%2C31585%2C2625%2C1729%2C7201%2C14417%2C64545%2C51345%2C11425%2C58625%2C11553%2C31057%2C2449%2C33105%2C3665%2C9729%2C57681%2C55889%2C51569%2C54785%2C1409%2C4913%2C56145%2C5473%2C6465%2C59393%2C16417%2C31825%2C145%2C10497%2C41249%2C32337%2C1393%2C51585%2C61553%2C10001%2C4689%2C2561%2C11857%2C52753%2C12961%2C35857%2C58113%2C35585%2C41761%2C57169%2C2321';
$tier7 = '19457%2C33825%2C37121%2C33041%2C36881%2C529%2C16129%2C1569%2C11681%2C5217%2C2337%2C5457%2C3633%2C513%2C49921%2C7233%2C12705%2C1121%2C35089%2C3153%2C18961%2C1793%2C3873%2C32865%2C4113%2C2305%2C1649%2C3857%2C6977%2C1665%2C36097%2C2705%2C36609%2C5281%2C33553%2C14753%2C7729%2C37633%2C10065%2C56353%2C15649%2C55569%2C56609%2C26177%2C11025%2C5889%2C7969%2C16289%2C55297%2C3377%2C11345%2C6657%2C10817%2C8961%2C9249%2C57617%2C1297%2C8977%2C19745%2C32049%2C305%2C59937%2C11041%2C14161%2C26945%2C54097%2C10769%2C59137%2C10241%2C59649%2C63809%2C3969%2C32849%2C5185%2C61713%2C15265%2C12545%2C39457%2C62993%2C1985%2C14353%2C14497%2C46593%2C35409%2C31761%2C1073%2C55121%2C32017%2C36177';

$i = 5;

while ($i<=7)
{
    $tierX = 'tier'.$i;
    $getXtier = ('https://urlsait='.$$tierX);
    echo $getXtier."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже упоминали авторы выше, правильнее в подобных случаях использовать массивы.

Но, раз уж потребность в составлении имени переменной с учётом значения другой переменной, возникла, могу предложить такой вариант:

```
$tierX = ${"tier".$i};
```

С учётом цикла, PHP будет обрабатывать данную строку как:

```
$tierX = $tier1;
```

В следующей итерации цикла:

```
$tierX = $tier2;
```

И так далее.

Answer (score 0):

**Все получилось, используя массив**.

Переменные держу в другой странице php и вызвал их через include;

```
include "tierlink.php";

$tierX = array ($tier5, $tier6, $tier7);

foreach ($tierX as $tier)
{
$getXtier = ('https://urlsait='.$tier);
echo $getXtier."<br>";
}
```